# Comparing two lists and only printing the differences? (XORing two lists)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a function that takes in 2 lists and returns the list that only has the differences of the two lists.

Example:

```
a = [1,2,5,7,9]
b = [1,2,4,8,9]
```

The result should print `[4,5,7,8]`

The function so far:

```
def xor(list1, list2):
    list3=list1+list2
    for i in range(0, len(list3)):
        x=list3[i]
        y=i
        while y>0 and x<list3[y-1]:
            list3[y]=list3[y-1]
            y=y-1
        list3[y]=x

        last=list3[-1]
    for i in range(len(list3) -2, -1, -1):
        if last==list3[i]:
            del list3[i]
        else:
            last=list3[i]

    return list3 
print xor([1,2,5,7,8],[1,2,4,8,9])
```

The first for loop sorts it, second one removes the duplicates. Problem is the result is 
`[1,2,4,5,7,8,9]` not `[4,5,7,8]`, so it doesn't completely remove the duplicates? What can I add to do this. 
I can't use any special modules, .sort, set or anything, just loops basically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You basically want to add an element to your new list if it is present in one and not present in another. Here is a compact loop which can do it. For each element in the two lists (concatenate them with `list1+list2`), we add element if it is not present in one of them:

```
[a for a in list1+list2 if (a not in list1) or (a not in list2)]
```

You can easily transform it into a more unPythonic code with explicit looping through elements as you have now, but honestly I don't see a point (not that it matters):

```
def xor(list1, list2):
    outputlist = []
    list3 = list1 + list2
    for i in range(0, len(list3)):
        if ((list3[i] not in list1) or (list3[i] not in list2)) and (list3[i] not in outputlist):
             outputlist[len(outputlist):] = [list3[i]]
    return outputlist
```

Comment: I think i understand what it's doing, but how would I make this into a full loop and do I add this loop to the original function or is would this work on its own...

Comment: This is a one-liner which does the function you are creating... You loop through list1+list2 elements x and have two if's: 1. if element in list1, make flag1=True, 2. if element in list2, make flag2=True; If (flag1 and flag2) != True and x not in outputlist, add it to outputlist.

Comment: @user2314520 What sashkello means is that any list comprehension is equivalent to a `for` loop over the items of the iterable, that adds said items to a new list if they match the condition, and then using the resultant list.

Comment: @user2314520, I've added a long version.

Comment: @user2314520: another way to look at it is: it finds a union of both lists without including an intersection of the lists (i.e., it find [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)). Union is `list1 + list2`. An element `x` is in the intersection if `x` is in `list1` and `x` is in `list2`; you want to exclude such elements so the condition should be reversed: `not (x in list1 and x in list2)` that is equivalent to `x not in list1 or x not in list2`. Putting it all together `xor_list = [x for x in (list1 + list2) if x not in list1 or x not in list2]`.

Comment: @sashkello: [here's a slightly more readable version of your multiline code](http://ideone.com/4hqnnE) (note: it keeps duplicates if they present only in one list (as well as the code that uses list comprehension)).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks, yep, I assumed we don't have (and probably don't want) duplicates.

Answer (score 20):

Use set is better

```
>>> a = [1,2,5,7,9]
>>> b = [1,2,4,8,9]
>>> set(a).symmetric_difference(b)
{4, 5, 7, 8}
```

Thanks to @DSM, a better sentence is:

```
>>> set(a)^set(b)
```

These two statements are the same. But the latter is clearer.

Update: sorry, I did not see the last requirement: cannot use set. As far as I see, the solution provided by @sashkello is the best.

Comment: Good answer for nonhomework, but 'I can't use any special modules, .sort, set or anything, just loops basically.'

Comment: Why not simply `set(a) ^ set(b)`, if we're using sets?

Comment: @DSM Thanks, your suggestin is better. I just forget the grammar.

Comment: I actually like `symmetric_difference` as much as `^`, but I prefer either to the original long version you had.  But you changed it to `symmetric_difference` at the same time I commented. :^)

Comment: @Sheng's update, we can convert it to list by simply list(set(a)^set(b)) # returns a list

Answer (score 5):

Note: This is really unpythonic and should only be used as a homework answer :)

After you have sorted both lists, you can find duplicates by doing the following:

1) Place iterators at the start of A and B

2) If Aitr is greater than Bitr, advance Bitr after placing Bitr's value in the return list

3) Else if Bitr is greater than Aitr, advance Aiter after placing Aitr's value in the return list

4) Else you have found a duplicate, advance Aitr and Bitr

Comment: Why do you think that your approach is unpythonic?

Comment: @gnibbler See Sheng's answer for what I consider pythonic

Comment: That relies on the elements all being hashable though. (They probably are)

Comment: [two implementations of the algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312730/comparing-two-lists-and-only-printing-the-differences-xoring-two-lists#comment23385899_16313781).

Answer (score 3):

This code works assuming you've got sorted lists. It works in linear time, rather than quadratic like many of the other solutions given.

```
def diff(sl0, sl1):
    i0, i1 = 0, 0
    while i0 < len(sl0) and i1 < len(sl1):
        if sl0[i0] == sl1[i1]:
            i0 += 1
            i1 += 1
        elif sl0[i0] < sl1[i1]:
            yield sl0[i0]
            i0 += 1
        else:
            yield sl1[i1]
            i1 += 1
    for i in xrange(i0, len(sl0)):
        yield sl0[i]
    for i in xrange(i1, len(sl1)):
        yield sl1[i]

print list(diff([1,2,5,7,9], [1,2,4,8,9]))
```

Comment: +1 for the linear solution. In general, [you could adapt it to  accept any iterable](http://ideone.com/8bKqVB), essentially implementing [@Patashu's algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16312759/4279).

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
    a = [1,2,5,7,9]
    b = [1,2,4,8,9]
 print set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, but not particularly efficient :)

```
>>> a = [1,2,5,7,9]
>>> b = [1,2,4,8,9]
>>> [i for i in a+b if (a+b).count(i)==1]
[5, 7, 4, 8]
```

Or with "just loops"

```
>>> res = []
>>> for i in a+b:
...  c = 0
...  for j in a+b:
...   if i==j:
...    c += 1
...  if c == 1:
...   res.append(i)
... 
>>> res
[5, 7, 4, 8]
```